# AWS API Gateway fails to fetch Apple /.well-known/openid-configuration

Tags: aws-api-gateway, openid-connect, aws-serverless, apple-id

I have a SAM template that defines the following API:

```
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      FailOnWarnings: true     # <--- it succeeds without this
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          AppleSignIn:
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
              - com.domain.MyApp
              issuer: "https://appleid.apple.com"
            IdentitySource: "$request.header.Authorization"
```

When I run this with FailOnWarnings:true, I get this warning (which is treated as an error):

> Resource handler returned message:
> Warnings found during import:  Unable to create Authorizer
> 'AppleSignIn':   Caught exception when connecting to
> https://appleid.apple.com/.well-known/openid-configuration for issuer
> https://appleid.apple.com. Please try again later. Error: Invalid
> issuer: https://appleid.apple.com. Issuer must have a valid discovery
> endpoint ended with '/.well-known/openid-configuration'. Ignoring.
> (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
> BadRequestException; Request ID: 409*removed*8b6;
> Proxy: null) (Service: null; Status Code: 404; Error Code:
> BadRequestException; Request ID: null; Proxy: null) (RequestToken: 43f*removed*3b9, HandlerErrorCode:
> GeneralServiceException)

However, as far as I can tell, https://appleid.apple.com/.well-known/openid-configuration is available and valid -- not sure why it would fail with 400 or 404. If I remove FailOnWarnings, it can deploy and the authorizer works, but I prefer to keep it strict.